# How to find file location using the regular expression ("*" in the path)?

Tags: python, python-os

Following `cp` linux command is working fine to find a file `"/home/temp/test-1.34.56/sample"` to current location

**Shell command:** Working fine

```
cp "/home/temp/test-*/sample" "./"
```

**Python code:**
It not working using `os.rename`

```
os.rename("/home/temp/test-*/sample", "./")
```

any other options ?

Comment: It sounds like you need the [glob module](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/glob.html)

Comment: `*` is not a regular expression. You're talking about globs, which Python has [a stdlib module for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Comment: @Tom FYI that's not the official docs, and it's out-of-date since "latest" there is 3.7, which is nearing EOL.

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah I think you're right.  I think [this is the correct one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Comment: `os.rename` is not really a close match for the Shell `cp` command. Have a looka at [shutil.copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) for a function that behaves like `cp`. This does not save you from iterating over `glob.glob` though.

Comment: Try this: `os.system('cp "/home/temp/test-*/sample" "./"')` it will just execute your linux command

Comment: Hey wait, globs don't work inside quotes. Is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks Wjandrea, Tom, Treuss.  glob module worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried glob module from above @Wjandrea, @Tom, @Treuss comments. it worked

```
from glob import glob
import shutil


actual_path = glob("/home/temp/test-*/sample")
if actual_path:
     shutil.move(actual_path[0],"./")
```